# UpdateFormValue action not updating FormControl value

Tags: angular, nativescript, ngxs

I am using ngxs with form plugin as my state management for my Nativescript app.

What I want is to update a form control value manually. I have created a following form:

```
 this.form = this.fb.group({
   type: [''],
 })
```

I rendered it on my html like so:

```
<StackLayout [formGroup]="form" ngxsForm="transactionHistory.filterForm" class="form">
  <FlexboxLayout>
    <DatePickerField hint="&#xf133; Select from " width="50%" class="fas date-select"></DatePickerField>
    <DatePickerField hint="&#xf133; Select to" width="50%" class="fas date-select"></DatePickerField>
  </FlexboxLayout>
  <FlexboxLayout>
    <Button (tap)="onChooseType()" [text]="selectedType + ' &#xf078;'" class="dropdown-btn fas"></Button>
    <Button text="All status &#xf078;" class="dropdown-btn fas"></Button>
  </FlexboxLayout>
  <FlexboxLayout>
    <Button text="All Payment Options &#xf078;" class="dropdown-btn fas po" width="100%"></Button>
  </FlexboxLayout>
  <FlexboxLayout justifyContent="flex-end">
    <Button text="Reset Filters" class="btn-reset"></Button>
    <Button (tap)="submit()" text="Apply" class="btn-apply"></Button>
  </FlexboxLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is my state class:

```
export class TransactionHistoryStateModel {
  transactions: PaginatedList<Transaction>;
  loading: boolean;
  filterForm: any;
  availableTypes: any;
}

@State({
  name: 'transactionHistory',
  defaults: {
    transactions: null,
    loading: false,
    filterForm: {
      model: undefined,
      dirty: false,
      status: '',
      errors: {},
      selectedType: 'All Types',
    },
    availableTypes: TRANSACTION_HISTORY_TYPE_MAPPING
  }
})
export class TransactionHistoryState {
  constructor(private client: HttpClient, private store: Store) {

  }

  @Action(HandleChosenType)
  handleChosenType({ setState, getState, dispatch }: StateContext<TransactionHistoryStateModel>, { selectedItem }: HandleChosenType) {
    const state = getState();
    const filterForm = state.filterForm;
    filterForm.selectedType = selectedItem.text;

    setState({
      ...state,
      filterForm
    });

    return dispatch(new UpdateFormValue({ 
      value: 'WAH' , 
      path: 'transactionHistory.filterForm.type'
    }));
  }
}
```

As you can see, I manually update the form control value by dispatching UpdateFormValue action. However, when I tried to get the value of the control it is empty. Why is that so?

Thanks!

EDIT: I was actually able to update the state using:

```
  this.store.dispatch([
    new UpdateFormValue({ 
      value: [ {type: 'HAHA' }], 
      path: 'transactionHistory.filterForm'
    }),
  ]);
```

However, changes in state doesn't update values on my FormGroup. It's so weird.

Comment: yes, your last code is correct. Because `path` property is concatenated with `model`, so it becomes `transactioHistory.filterForm.model` (state name, object, model). Could you provide some simple example on the stackblitz? I cannot reproduce your problem, also I cannot run it in a nativescript app :)

Comment: @Shadow there is no nativescript support for stackblitz. I am starting to think that this has something to do with nativescript :( Can you suggest a wild guesses? :)

Comment: nah, I didn't mean to create nativescript app, I meant to create something similar to your example. Try to listen to the `valueChanges` stream and see if something is happening after `UpdateFormValue` action is handled

Comment: @Shadow ok, I think i have to test it :) Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem with my custom form control (not NativeScript), it was caused by missing logic in `writeValue` function (I simply forgot to add a property update for input element, so I couldn't see the changes).

Comment: did you got any solution??? I have a same case and its not working.